# UV Coords for screen quad not getting transformed

Tags: c#, graphics, glsl, opentk

I was making this open gl app where I needed to render the texture to a screen quad. My requirement is that the quad should be resized to the textures width and height for a specific reason. To test the resizing, I decided to have

```
transformation = Matrix4.CreateScale(0.5f,0.3f,0);
```

and I get the result
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf0Ty.png
I was able to recognize that the problem was that the uv coords weren't scaling accordingly.
Here is the vertex shader:

```
#version 460 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;
uniform mat4 model;

    void main()
    {
        TexCoord = aTexCoord;
        gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0f) * model;
    }
```

The uv coords are correct and displays when it is normal.. I thought it was supposed to show the entire image in the scale..

Thank You.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update: I fixed the problem..
**The main reason:** The reason was because I had some postprocessing effects and the things is, I didn't use texcoord for sample I just calculated the screen uvs.. Dumb me oh well!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).